# Como chamar uma função em outra função para fazer um teste de requisição GET GOLANG

Tags: golang

Sou iniciante na linguagem Go e atualmente trabalho com redes estava querendo criar um sistema onde eu possa fazer requisições GET para monitorar o site da empresa, porem estou na duvida onde eu criei uma função que recebe o input (url ou ip) e outra onde faz a requisição porem esta dando erro segue abaixo o codigo:

```golang
func leSitemonitora() {
    var Sitemonitora string
    fmt.Scanln(&Sitemonitora)
    fmt.Println("Site a ser monitorado foi", Sitemonitora)

}

func iniciarmonitoramento() {
    fmt.Println("Iniciando Monitoramento...")
    resp, _ := http.Get()
    fmt.Println(resp)

}
```

Comment: Que erro está sendo gerado?

Comment: O autor da resposta orientou *...Por fim, sua pergunta não ficou clara pois não sabemos que erro ocorreu. Da próxima vez tente seguir [essas dicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para elaborar suas perguntas e assim ajudar a comunidade a te ajudar...*

Answer (score 1):

Existem vários erros dentro do seu código, o primeiro é que a sua função que obtem a url a ser monitorada não faz nada com ela, poderia tanto ser salva em uma variável global (não recomendado) como ser retornada pela função (recomendado). Logo essa função poderia ser algo assim:

```golang
func leSiteMonitora() (site string) {
    fmt.Println("Entre com a url que deseja ser monitorada:")
    fmt.Scanln(&site)
    // Valida se a url tem o prefixo correto
    if !strings.HasPrefix(site, "http://") {
        site = "http://" + site
    }
    fmt.Println("Site a ser monitorado foi", site)

    return
}
```

O segundo erro é que você não está informando url nenhuma na sua chamada `http.Get()`, logo o sistema não sabe o que chamar. A correção poderia ser desta forma:

```golang
func iniciarmonitoramento(site string) {
    fmt.Println("Iniciando Monitoramento do site:", site)
    resp, _ := http.Get(site)
    fmt.Println(resp)

}
```

e por fim a chamada na sua `main` poderia ser assim:

```golang
func main() {
    iniciarmonitoramento(leSiteMonitora())
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Augusto, estou estudando sozinho, mais obrigado mesmo assim pela explicação